# Combining multiple mysql queries to 1 output

Tags: mysql, union

what am I doing wrong here, as I am trying to get all outputs from both queries below in 1 query, i.e,

count(centerpoint_stream_stable), date,website_online,icecast_source_online, icecast_source_ip,icecast_no_listeners,centerpoint_online, centerpoint_connection,centerpoint_stream_stable,centerpoint_stream_status,     horsleypark_online,horsleypark_connection,horsleypark_stream_stable, horsleypark_stream_status,local_primary_internet_online, local_primary_internet_ping,local_primary_instreamer_online, local_secondary_internet_online,local_secondary_internet_ping, local_secondary_instreamer_online, system_ok
The 2 queries i would like to union are

```
select count(centerpoint_stream_stable) from status_log where  centerpoint_stream_stable = 'Disconnected/ Reconnected to Stream' and  date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ;
```

and

```
SELECT date, website_online, icecast_source_online, icecast_source_ip, icecast_no_listeners, centerpoint_online, centerpoint_connection, centerpoint_stream_stable,centerpoint_stream_status,  horsleypark_online, horsleypark_connection,horsleypark_stream_stable,horsleypark_stream_status, local_primary_internet_online,local_primary_internet_ping, local_primary_instreamer_online,local_secondary_internet_online,local_secondary_internet_ping,local_secondary_instreamer_online,system_ok FROM status_log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

the union of both queries above below is giving the following error;

> ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

```
(select * from (select 
        date, 
    website_online, 
    icecast_source_online, 
    icecast_source_ip, 
    icecast_no_listeners, 
    centerpoint_online, 
    centerpoint_connection,     
    centerpoint_stream_stable,
    centerpoint_stream_status,      
    horsleypark_online, 
    horsleypark_connection,
    horsleypark_stream_stable,
    horsleypark_stream_status, 
    local_primary_internet_online,
    local_primary_internet_ping,        
    local_primary_instreamer_online,    
    local_secondary_internet_online,    
    local_secondary_internet_ping,
    local_secondary_instreamer_online,
    system_ok
FROM status_log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1))


union all
(select * from (select count(centerpoint_stream_stable) from status_log where  centerpoint_stream_stable = 'Disconnected/ Reconnected to Stream' and  date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ));
```

Comment: if you create a subquery you need to name it: `(select * from t) as alias_table_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses are used for subqueries and then you have to give each subquery an alias like the error is suggesting. Example:

```
(SELECT id FROM table1) a
UNION
(SELECT id FROM table2) b
```

More importantly, when you use `UNION`, all the fields in both query must exactly match. Your to queries have completely different fields.

**EDIT** `UNION` is to add the results from the first query to the results of the second query. In your case, you're not trying to add the results together, you are trying to add the fields together. For that, you can use joins or subqueries. Try this with sub queries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT (s2.centerpoint_stream_stable)
        FROM status_log s2
        WHERE s2.id = s.id
          AND s2.centerpoint_stream_stable = 'Disconnected/ Reconnected to Stream'
          AND s2.date > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) AS my_count,

       s.date, s.website_online, s.icecast_source_online, s.icecast_source_ip,
       s.icecast_no_listeners, s.centerpoint_online, s.centerpoint_connection,
       s.centerpoint_stream_stable, s.centerpoint_stream_status,  s.horsleypark_online,
       s.horsleypark_connection, s.horsleypark_stream_stable, s.horsleypark_stream_status,
       s.local_primary_internet_online, s.local_primary_internet_ping,
       s.local_primary_instreamer_online, s.local_secondary_internet_online,
       s.local_secondary_internet_ping, s.local_secondary_instreamer_online, s.system_ok
FROM status_log s
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I made your first query as a subquery. It gives you the first count field. I called it `my_count`, but you can change that to whatever you like.

In order to join the two queries together, you need to provide the joining condition, so I added the condition `s2.id = s.id` to your first query.

I don't know why you have `LIMIT 1` at the end of your second query. That will give you one record which has the biggest `id`.

Comment: Parentheses in union queries do sometimes make sense  or are even necessary. For instance when using `order by` or `limit`.

Comment: thanks, but i am just a noob, could you provide correct use, solution

Comment: Read my last sentence. All fields must match. The two queries that you have cannot be combined with a `UNION`. Edit your question and explain what you're trying to achieve so we can help you.

Comment: Um, you said don't use them

Comment: Ossama, check my updated answer to your updated question.

Comment: i tried your answer, however my_count always returns 0 no matter what. if i run this query i get other values: select count(centerpoint_stream_stable) from status_log where  centerpoint_stream_stable = 'Disconnected/ Reconnected to Stream' and  date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) )

Comment: i had to make few mods to your answer to make it work:  SELECT (SELECT count(s2.centerpoint_stream_stable)
        FROM status_log s2
        WHERE s2.centerpoint_stream_stable = 'Disconnected/ Reconnected to Stream'
          AND s2.date